# can't boot into recovery anymore

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, asus-eee-pad-transformer, twrp

I am using CM10 nightly version and TWRP for tf201. Wanted to try the unofficial CM11 version android 4.4 on my tablet and it says that is not compatible with this recovery, so I downloaded the latest version of CWM 5.8 from its website and using adb fastboot (and second time with the tablet terminal) flashed the new recovery over the older one.
Now the problem is I can't enter the recovery mode, it gets stuck while entering the mode. I tried that procedure with two more recent version of CWM (both touch and classic) and also its ROM manager but the problem persists. Some info:

1- I have my device unlocked, rooted
2- adb fastboot said completely Done while flashing
3- i could see the blue bar completed on the tf201 device and then i used fastboot reboot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that if I run into problems with the custom recovery, I can get rid of it altogether by re-flashing the stock firmware, and then I can install the custom recovery again. You have a different device, but that's what works on a Samsung Galaxy S4, so it might work for you. Of course, there's always the possibility that if you try installing CWM again you'll run into the same problems, but at least that should let you start again from square one, as if you had never flashed a custom recovery in the first place.

Comment: I have mentioned it, its tf201 (asus transformer prime)

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear to me that that was a device model. In any case, my suggestion remains the same.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. I will try that and report the results here

Comment: Now we have a problem: I can't seem to find my stock recovery! where should I download that from ?

Comment: That's device-specific. I don't know details like that for your device since that's not what I use. On a Galaxy phone, though, you don't flash firmware from recovery (stock or custom). There's a download mode called Odin that you enter with a different combination of hard buttons. Does your device have something like that--a download mode for flashing firmware? Galaxy firmware can also be flashed using software installed on a connected PC (Kies), maybe there's something like that for your device?

Comment: No i don't think so, i can find the stock ROM in the vip.asus website but no stock booloader. I tried to flash again to TWRP and using ROM manager is says that this bootloader is there but i can't boot there, it get stucks

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have experience with your device. The Galaxy bootloader in recent firmware versions can't be unlocked, which may be a blessing in disguise: You have to use Safestrap as the custom recovery, so the stock and custom recoveries coexist. Based on reading [this](http://forums.androidcentral.com/asus-transformer-pad-infinity-700/336920-tutorial-flashing-custom-rom-tf700t.html), it sounds like on your device, if you flash a custom recovery, it obliterates the stock recovery (which is more typical).

Comment: However, the stock recovery should be part of the stock firmware, so if you use TWRP to flash the stock ROM, you should have the stock recovery again (with TWRP committing suicide in the process). [This thread](http://www.oppoforums.com/threads/how-to-get-stock-recovery-after-twrp-install.3684/) seems to corroborate that it works that way. Did you try flashing the stock ROM in the Stock ROM slot from TWRP?

Comment: I think so. I did flash with twrp the first time

Comment: well, I found two version of my stock android JB 4.1 and flash them, on both occasions after `fastboot reboot`, the tablet stucks at the pre-OS loading screen

Comment: Are you saying that it bootloops now--doesn't start up at all, let alone getting into the custom recovery? Man, I can't tell you how many times I've soft-bricked my test phone that way while experimenting with custom recoveries and ROMs, and I've been able to fix it every single time by flashing the stock ROM with Odin (and usually without the need for a factory reset, so settings and data remain intact). Does Asus have any utilities at all for flashing the ROM without using a custom recovery? It seems that there would *have* to be, for situations like this.

Comment: Yes, Actually I resolved the bootloader issue, now it has its stock bootloader and i dont care if it fails booting the stock android. I managed to flash the very first TWRP 2.8 to the system and now I can boot into custom recovery. STILL DON'T KNOW WHY IT FAILED WITH THOSE CWM !!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you're back in business. Just a thought, maybe it's not all those versions of CWM that failed. Maybe just the first one messed things up, and the others seemed not to work because the bootloader or recovery was already hosed. You might want to try again, starting with the most recent version. Then again, you might want to avoid inviting further headaches. ;)

Comment: Yes, sure. I found the very latest CWM 6 and it worked finally. I am on CM11 android 4.4 now ! ;) cheers